# How to find the ID of an alsa capture device by name?

Tags: alsa

With `recordmydesktop`, the input device is specified with an id, e.g: `-device plughw:5,0`.

This has the problem that plugging in web-cams and other devices may change the index.

How can I calculate this value using the name of the device?

Answer (score 0):

`arecord -l` can be used to list capture devices.

This can be used to find the index, although it doesn't seem like the best option.

For example:

Assuming I want to match the card that outputs.

```sh
card 5: A4 [AIR 192 4], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
```

```sh
CARD_INDEX="$(arecord -l | pcregrep -io1 '^card ([\d]+): A4 \[AIR 192 4\]')"
```